# How to place the | symbol to match either of two regex patterns using stringr::str_match?

Tags: r, regex, stringr, stringi

The different formats found in `df$PlateName` are:

```
    MIPS_AGRE_P01_DIL
    MIPS_SSC_P50_DIL
    MIPS_MtS_P34
    MIPS_AT_P1_DIL
    KORgex.mips.G12
    MIPS_SSC_CL_P32_DIL
    MIPS_SSC_CL_Low_DIL
```

Using this regex, which is very clunky, returns the following types:

```
str_match(df$PlateName, 
          "MIPS_([:alnum:]+(?:_[:alnum:]+)?)_[Low|P:digit:]+(?:_[DIL])?|(KORgex).*")) %>%
  as.tibble %>% 
  count(V2)
```

All the NA ones are the `KORgex.mips.G12` types. How can I make this regex work?

```
AGRE    1654            
AT      93          
MtS     1324            
SSC     5280            
SSC_CL  288         
NA      529
```

---

**UPDATE:**

I realized that it's probably better to use `str_extract` in this case, as that will return only the matching portion of every component of `df$PlateName`.

I still can't quite get the code to return what I need - what am I missing?

```
str_extract(data$PlateName, "[[:alnum:]+^(?!(MIPS))]_([[:alnum:]&&[^P]]+(_CL)?)?|(KORgex)") %>% 
as.tibble  %>% 
count(value)`
```

returns:

```
KORgex      529         
S_AGRE      1654            
S_AT        93          
S_MtS       1324            
S_SSC       5280            
S_SSC_CL    288
```

I cannot for the life of me get rid of the `S_` in the `MIPS_` subtypes!

Comment: What's the desired output for `KORgex.mips.G12` entry?

Comment: I'd like to get back just `KORgex`.

Comment: Not sure all the reproducible code is provided, the output of `stringr::str_match` (stringr_1.3.0) is not the output you have with the numeric second column, can you check?  My output is 3 columns, 1st column is the complete match, 2nd and 3rd column are the capture groups, with the 3rd column capturing `KORgex` properly. See output value of `?str_match`

Comment: My apologies, the output I pasted corresponds to a count I did after grouping the new column.

Comment: Can you add that code? Is that the count table for the 2nd column? Would the count table for the 3rd column give you what you want?

Comment: Just added the code. Thank you, I just realized it was returning the matches to `KOR.gex` in a second column -- but what I really want is a single column with a match to either pattern, so a collapsed version of cols 2 and 3.

Comment: Just realized that `str_extract` is proably better for what I need, but my regex still needs some help!

Answer (score 2):

The best thing we could do here is using a [branch reset group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html), `(?|...|...)` to only get one group instead of multiple ones.

However, the `stringr`/`stringi` functions in R are bases on the [ICU regex flavor](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp), which does not support branch reset groups.

The most convenient way to use a branch reset here is via `grep`:

```
grep(df$PlateName, 
  "(?|MIPS_([:alnum:]+(?:_[:alnum:]+)?)_[Low|P:digit:]+(?:_[DIL])?|(KORgex).*)", perl=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work. After messing around with `str_match` for awhile, I decided it was just easier to use `str_replace` to remove everything you didn't want.

```
df$PlateName %>%
  str_replace("([[:alpha:]]+_)?([[:alpha:]]+)(_CL)?(_|\\.)??.*", "\\2\\3") %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  count(value)
```

Comment: Just realized that `str_extract` is proably better for what I need, but my regex still needs some help!

Answer (score 2):

```r
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

#this step places "|" symbol to match either of two regex patterns
str_match(df$PlateName, "MIPS_(\\S+)_[P|Low].*|(KORgex).*") %>%
  #convert to dataframe to count its occurrences
  data.frame(stringsAsFactors=F) %>%
  mutate(sub_PlateName = coalesce(X2, X3)) %>%
  group_by(sub_PlateName) %>%
  tally()
```

**Output is:**

```
  sub_PlateName     n
1 AGRE              1
2 AT                1
3 KORgex            1
4 MtS               1
5 SSC               1
6 SSC_CL            2
```

**Sample data:**

```
df <- structure(list(PlateName = c("MIPS_AGRE_P01_DIL", "MIPS_SSC_P50_DIL", 
"MIPS_MtS_P34", "MIPS_AT_P1_DIL", "KORgex.mips.G12", "MIPS_SSC_CL_P32_DIL", 
"MIPS_SSC_CL_Low_DIL")), .Names = "PlateName", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

**Update:**
Using `str_extract`

```
str_extract(df$PlateName, "(?<=MIPS_)\\S+(?=_P|_Low)|KORgex") %>% 
  as.tibble %>% 
  count(value)
#   value     n
#1   AGRE     1
#2     AT     1
#3 KORgex     1
#4    MtS     1
#5    SSC     1
#6 SSC_CL     2
```

Comment: Thank you - Just realized that `str_extract` is proably better for what I need, but my regex still needs some help!